# caching iterable in arraylist for iterating twice in reducer doesn't work

Tags: java, hadoop, arraylist, mapreduce, iterable

I have some weird problem with my MR program and don't know why it is working this way.
Maybe can give me a hint whats wrong with it ?

That's how my Mapper function looks like:

```
    Integer Click_ID = 0;

  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException , InterruptedException
  {

      String line = value.toString();

      String []lineArr = line.split("\t");

      String nm_uv_id = lineArr[0];
      String session_id = lineArr[1];
      String time_stamp = lineArr[2];
      String click_counter = lineArr[3];
      String is_robot = lineArr[4];

      Click_ID++;

      String full_line =  Click_ID + "\t"+ nm_uv_id +"\t"+ session_id+"\t"+time_stamp+"\t"+click_counter+"\t"+ is_robot;


      context.write(new Text(session_id), new Text(full_line));

   }
```

Up to here everything works fine - my mapper produces the expected output, when I set the number of Reducers = 0.

Here is how my Reducer looks like. What I want to do, is to iterate twice through each Iterable of my keys. Doing that, I tried to cache every value of my Iterable in a separate ArrayList:

```
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    List<Text> cache = new ArrayList<Text>();

           // first iterable
    for (Text value : values) {
                                       cache.add(value); }

           //second iterable
        for (Text entity : cache) {

            context.write(key, entity);  }
    }
```

}

My Input I use for the MR looks like this:

```
nm_uv_id_1  session_id_2    1234567891  1   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_1  session_id_2    1234567892  2   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_1  session_id_2    1234567893  3   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_1  session_id_2    1234567894  3   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567895  1   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567896  2   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567897  3   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567898  4   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567899  5   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567888  6   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567890  7   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567890  8   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567890  9   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567890  10  is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_1  session_id_3    1234567890  1   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_2  session_id_4    1234587890  1   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_2  session_id_4    1234587890  2   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_2  session_id_4    1234587890  3   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_2  session_id_4    1234587890  4   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_2  session_id_4    1234587890  5   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_2  session_id_4    1234587890  6   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_2  session_id_4    1234587890  7   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_2  session_id_4    1234587890  8   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_2  session_id_4    1234587890  9   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_2  session_id_5    1234587890  1   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_2  session_id_5    1234587890  2   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_2  session_id_5    1234587890  3   is_robot_yes
nm_uv_id_2  session_id_5    1234587890  4   is_robot_yes
nm_uv_id_2  session_id_5    1234587890  5   is_robot_no
nm_uv_id_2  session_id_5    123457890   6   is_robot_no
```

However my Output file looks like this:

```
session_id_1    13  nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567890  9   is_robot_no
session_id_1    13  nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567890  9   is_robot_no
session_id_1    13  nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567890  9   is_robot_no
session_id_1    13  nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567890  9   is_robot_no
session_id_1    13  nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567890  9   is_robot_no
session_id_1    13  nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567890  9   is_robot_no
session_id_1    13  nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567890  9   is_robot_no
session_id_1    13  nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567890  9   is_robot_no
session_id_1    13  nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567890  9   is_robot_no
session_id_1    13  nm_uv_id_1  session_id_1    1234567890  9   is_robot_no
session_id_2    2   nm_uv_id_1  session_id_2    1234567892  2   is_robot_no
session_id_2    2   nm_uv_id_1  session_id_2    1234567892  2   is_robot_no
session_id_2    2   nm_uv_id_1  session_id_2    1234567892  2   is_robot_no
session_id_2    2   nm_uv_id_1  session_id_2    1234567892  2   is_robot_no
session_id_3    15  nm_uv_id_1  session_id_3    1234567890  1   is_robot_no
session_id_4    24  nm_uv_id_2  session_id_4    1234587890  9   is_robot_no
session_id_4    24  nm_uv_id_2  session_id_4    1234587890  9   is_robot_no
session_id_4    24  nm_uv_id_2  session_id_4    1234587890  9   is_robot_no
session_id_4    24  nm_uv_id_2  session_id_4    1234587890  9   is_robot_no
session_id_4    24  nm_uv_id_2  session_id_4    1234587890  9   is_robot_no
session_id_4    24  nm_uv_id_2  session_id_4    1234587890  9   is_robot_no
session_id_4    24  nm_uv_id_2  session_id_4    1234587890  9   is_robot_no
session_id_4    24  nm_uv_id_2  session_id_4    1234587890  9   is_robot_no
session_id_4    24  nm_uv_id_2  session_id_4    1234587890  9   is_robot_no
session_id_5    30  nm_uv_id_2  session_id_5    123457890   6   is_robot_no
session_id_5    30  nm_uv_id_2  session_id_5    123457890   6   is_robot_no
session_id_5    30  nm_uv_id_2  session_id_5    123457890   6   is_robot_no
session_id_5    30  nm_uv_id_2  session_id_5    123457890   6   is_robot_no
session_id_5    30  nm_uv_id_2  session_id_5    123457890   6   is_robot_no
session_id_5    30  nm_uv_id_2  session_id_5    123457890   6   is_robot_no
```

I don't unterstand why the reducer always writes  the same key-value pair for one specific key. I tried several things and it seems that the first for-loop, where I do the caching works fine. When I would write context.write(key,value) I get my expected output.
 However the second, when i want to use the cache in the second for-loop the programm writes some weird stuff for me.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is reusing the same `Text` buffer as an optimization. So you will need to manually clone to cache it.

I would just alter your cache-loop:

```
for (Text value : values) { cache.add(new Text(value)); }
```